# RoR Heroku deploy error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I run "`$ git push heroku`",

I get the following before the "Heroku receiving push" message.

> Davids-iMac:requestsys burtondav$ git push heroku key_read: uudecode
>   AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAu8erSx6jh+8ztsfHwkNeFr/SZaSOcvoa8AyMpaerGIPZDB2TKNgNkMSYTLYGDK2ivsqXopo2W7dpQRBIVF80q9mNXy5tbt1WE04gbOBB26Wn2hF4bk3Tu+BNMFbvMjPbkVlC2hcFuQJdH4T2i/dtauyTpJbD/6ExHR9XYVhdhdMs0JsjP/Q5FNoWh2ff9YbZVpDQSTPvusUp4liLjPfa/i0t+2LpNCeWy8Y+V9gUlDWiyYwrfMVI0UwNCZZKHs1Unpc11/4HLitQRtvuk0Ot5qwwBxbmtvCDKZvj1aFBid71/mYdGRPYZMIxq1zgP1acePC1zfTG/lvuQ7d0Pe0kaw==184.72.93.56
>   ssh-rsa
>   AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDoIUvF+Ac8P1hbg/FQFD+uP1Ds4opJWbJLM/+Jm8VmcJ6CnAW7OuT9cCabSGmPQrehV5KyWJ341YXu1m2c8VJe7k5KEfKWqm03NONwi6b9TeNa3WfIlACgulE9u7A9CJW1N8ntdk32PHzyWzvHU7llTGf4Mcnf81s6N+2frq6aoT4oRPkwWcFIRclpqMZZSDGPx27OctAsCm88EBt02fIwxuqOCzTEyVadvr3YHhWzkK5NBdG0NxxFoZ7qD7bCxO9yIwf7itsVn+8n0cgfK2etdWmTJ7z2JWIbHrk/qRVpHl2GoQqjyvoIVVOTUYCL6QMsFG29jVc1L9yo4yXlFlNj
>   failed key_read: uudecode
>   AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAu8erSx6jh+8ztsfHwkNeFr/SZaSOcvoa8AyMpaerGIPZDB2TKNgNkMSYTLYGDK2ivsqXopo2W7dpQRBIVF80q9mNXy5tbt1WE04gbOBB26Wn2hF4bk3Tu+BNMFbvMjPbkVlC2hcFuQJdH4T2i/dtauyTpJbD/6ExHR9XYVhdhdMs0JsjP/Q5FNoWh2ff9YbZVpDQSTPvusUp4liLjPfa/i0t+2LpNCeWy8Y+V9gUlDWiyYwrfMVI0UwNCZZKHs1Unpc11/4HLitQRtvuk0Ot5qwwBxbmtvCDKZvj1aFBid71/mYdGRPYZMIxq1zgP1acePC1zfTG/lvuQ7d0Pe0kaw==184.72.93.56
>   ssh-rsa
>   AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDoIUvF+Ac8P1hbg/FQFD+uP1Ds4opJWbJLM/+Jm8VmcJ6CnAW7OuT9cCabSGmPQrehV5KyWJ341YXu1m2c8VJe7k5KEfKWqm03NONwi6b9TeNa3WfIlACgulE9u7A9CJW1N8ntdk32PHzyWzvHU7llTGf4Mcnf81s6N+2frq6aoT4oRPkwWcFIRclpqMZZSDGPx27OctAsCm88EBt02fIwxuqOCzTEyVadvr3YHhWzkK5NBdG0NxxFoZ7qD7bCxO9yIwf7itsVn+8n0cgfK2etdWmTJ7z2JWIbHrk/qRVpHl2GoQqjyvoIVVOTUYCL6QMsFG29jVc1L9yo4yXlFlNj
>   failed Counting objects: 15, done. Delta compression using up to 4
>   threads. Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done. Writing objects: 100%
>   (8/8), 1.03 KiB, done. Total 8 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0)

Any idea what this means?

Thanks!!

Comment: are you typing this in? `git push heroku key_read: uudecode`

Comment: No - I'm just entering "$ git push heroku"

Comment: Your question says that you did type `key_read: uudecode`

Comment: is there any alias thing in your .bashrc/.bash_profile?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
git push heroku master # This would push to application on heroku
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether you have added the heroku keys by giving,

heroku keys

It will result something like,

=== dave@example.com Keys
ssh-dss AAAAB8NzaC...DVj3R4Ww== dave@workstation.local

If you have not uploaded the ssh keys to heroku then follow the URL below.
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys

After that, if you give the following command, it will work.

git push heroku master

Hope it helps.